# Pausing javascript game using style.display in if statements not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm working on a javascript game and trying to add some code to the button that toggles the visibility of the games and acts as a pause button so that it will stop running and not keep shoving scoring alerts down your throat if you have it hidden, and all of the code that I've written has failed miserably. Here it is, hope someone can help me fix it.

```html
<div id = 'games'>
<!-- I only put this canvas in a div because there will be more games here soon. -->
<canvas id='my' width = '640' height = '480'></canvas>
</div>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("my");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function paddle(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedModifier = 0;
    this.hasCollidedWith = function(ball) {
        var paddleLeftWall = this.x;
        var paddleRightWall = this.x + this.width;
        var paddleTopWall = this.y;
        var paddleBottomWall = this.y + this.height;
        if (ball.x > paddleLeftWall &&
            ball.x < paddleRightWall &&
            ball.y > paddleTopWall &&
            ball.y < paddleBottomWall) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    this.move = function(keyCode) {
        var nextY = this.y;
        if (keyCode == 40) {
            nextY += 5;
            this.speedModifer = 1.5;
        } else if (keyCode == 38) {
            nextY += -5;
            this.speedModifier = 1.5;
        } else {
            this.speedModifier = 0;
        }
        nextY = nextY < 0 ? 0 : nextY;
        nextY = nextY + this.height > 480 ? 480 - this.height : nextY;
        this.y = nextY;
    };
}
var player = new paddle(5, 200, 25, 100);

var ai = new paddle(610, 200, 25, 100);
var ball = {
    x: 320,
    y: 240,
    radius: 7,
    xSpeed: 2,
    ySpeed: 0,
    playerscore: 0,
    aiscore: 0,
    reverseX: function() {
        this.xSpeed *= -1;
    },
    reverseY: function() {
        this.ySpeed *= -1;
    },
    reset: function() {
        alert('The score is now ' + this.playerscore + ' to ' + this.aiscore);
        this.x = 20;
        this.y = 24;
        this.xSpeed = 2;
        this.ySpeed = 0;
        
    },
    isBouncing: function() {
        return ball.ySpeed != 0;
    },
    modifyXSpeedBy: function(modification) {
        modification = this.xSpeed < 0 ? modification * -1 : modification;
        var nextValue = this.xSpeed + modification;
        nextValue = Math.abs(nextValue) > 9 ? 9 : nextValue;
        this.xSpeed = nextValue;
    },
    modifyYSpeedBy: function(modification) {
     
   modification = this.ySpeed < 0 ? modification * -1 : modification;
        this.ySpeed += modification;
    }
};
function tick() {
   
   updateGame();
    draw()
    window.setTimeout("tick()", 1000 / 60);
}

function updateGame() {
    ball.x += ball.xSpeed;
    ball.y += ball.ySpeed;
    if (ball.x < 0) {
        ball.reset();
        ball.aiscore = ball.aiscore + 1;
        
    }
    if (ball.x > 640) {
        ball.reset();
        ball.playerscore = ball.playerscore + 1
        
    }
    if (ball.y <= 0 || ball.y >= 480) {
        ball.reverseY();
    }
    var collidedWithPlayer = player.hasCollidedWith(ball);
    var collidedWithAi = ai.hasCollidedWith(ball);
    if (collidedWithPlayer || collidedWithAi) {
        ball.reverseX();
        ball.modifyXSpeedBy(0.25);
        var speedUpValue = collidedWithPlayer ? player.speedModifier : ai.speedModifier;
        ball.modifyYSpeedBy(speedUpValue);
    }
    for (var keyCode in heldDown) {
        player.move(keyCode);
    }
    var aiMiddle = ai.y + (ai.height / 2);
    if (aiMiddle < ball.y) {
        ai.move(40);
    }
    if (aiMiddle > ball.y) {
        ai.move(38);
    }
    
}

function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
    renderPaddle(player);
    renderPaddle(ai);
    renderBall(ball);
}

function renderPaddle(paddle) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
}

function renderBall(ball) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
    ctx.fill();
}
var heldDown = {};
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(keyInfo) {
    heldDown[event.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(keyInfo) {
    delete heldDown[event.keyCode];
}, false);
function playPong(){
 if (canvas.style.display == 'none'){canvas.style.display = 'block';}
 else {canvas.style.display == 'none';}
if (canvas.style.display === 'block')
{
tick()};

}



</script>

<script>
function hide() {
var games = document.getElementById('games')
if (games.style.display === 'block')
games.style.display = 'none';
else{games.style.display = 'block';}
}
function show(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('my')
canvas.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>


<button onclick = 'hide()'> Hide or show the games</button>

<button onclick = 'playPong();show()'> Play pong </button>
```

Comment: hiding the canvas doesn't stop the javascript from running.  Add a check to your tick() method that verifies the canvas isn't hidden.  You may also want to call clearTimeout on the pending timeout.

Comment: Yeah, adding an if statement to my tick function does nothing.

Comment: It seems that's due how you implemented it. Show the code you tried for `tick()` that was supposed to work to pause the game but didn't.

Comment: If (canvas.style.display == 'block')  {tick();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try not using the visibility of the canvas as the deciding factor in the if statement and instead maybe trying something like this-

```html
<div id='games'>
  <canvas id='my' width='640' height='480'></canvas>
</div>
<script>
  var paused = false

  function PausePlay() {
    if (paused === false) {
      paused = true;
    } else {
      paused = false;
    }
  }
  var canvas = document.getElementById("my");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  function paddle(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedModifier = 0;
    this.hasCollidedWith = function(ball) {
      var paddleLeftWall = this.x;
      var paddleRightWall = this.x + this.width;
      var paddleTopWall = this.y;
      var paddleBottomWall = this.y + this.height;
      if (ball.x > paddleLeftWall &&
        ball.x < paddleRightWall &&
        ball.y > paddleTopWall &&
        ball.y < paddleBottomWall) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };
    this.move = function(keyCode) {
      var nextY = this.y;
      if (keyCode == 40) {
        nextY += 5;
        this.speedModifer = 1.5;
      } else if (keyCode == 38) {
        nextY += -5;
        this.speedModifier = 1.5;
      } else {
        this.speedModifier = 0;
      }
      nextY = nextY < 0 ? 0 : nextY;
      nextY = nextY + this.height > 480 ? 480 - this.height : nextY;
      this.y = nextY;
    };
  }
  var player = new paddle(5, 200, 25, 100);

  var ai = new paddle(610, 200, 25, 100);
  var ball = {
    x: 320,
    y: 240,
    radius: 7,
    xSpeed: 2,
    ySpeed: 0,
    playerscore: 0,
    aiscore: 0,
    reverseX: function() {
      this.xSpeed *= -1;
    },
    reverseY: function() {
      this.ySpeed *= -1;
    },
    reset: function() {
      alert('The score is now ' + this.playerscore + ' to ' + this.aiscore);
      this.x = 20;
      this.y = 24;
      this.xSpeed = 2;
      this.ySpeed = 0;

    },
    isBouncing: function() {
      return ball.ySpeed != 0;
    },
    modifyXSpeedBy: function(modification) {
      modification = this.xSpeed < 0 ? modification * -1 : modification;
      var nextValue = this.xSpeed + modification;
      nextValue = Math.abs(nextValue) > 9 ? 9 : nextValue;
      this.xSpeed = nextValue;
    },
    modifyYSpeedBy: function(modification) {

      modification = this.ySpeed < 0 ? modification * -1 : modification;
      this.ySpeed += modification;
    }
  };

  function tick() {


    updateGame();
    draw()
    window.setTimeout("tick()", 1000 / 60);

  }


  function updateGame() {
    if (paused === false) {
      ball.x += ball.xSpeed;
      ball.y += ball.ySpeed;
      if (ball.x < 0) {
        ball.reset();
        ball.aiscore = ball.aiscore + 1;

      }
      if (ball.x > 640) {
        ball.reset();
        ball.playerscore = ball.playerscore + 1

      }
      if (ball.y <= 0 || ball.y >= 480) {
        ball.reverseY();
      }
      var collidedWithPlayer = player.hasCollidedWith(ball);
      var collidedWithAi = ai.hasCollidedWith(ball);
      if (collidedWithPlayer || collidedWithAi) {
        ball.reverseX();
        ball.modifyXSpeedBy(0.25);
        var speedUpValue = collidedWithPlayer ? player.speedModifier : ai.speedModifier;
        ball.modifyYSpeedBy(speedUpValue);
      }
      for (var keyCode in heldDown) {
        player.move(keyCode);
      }
      var aiMiddle = ai.y + (ai.height / 2);
      if (aiMiddle < ball.y) {
        ai.move(40);
      }
      if (aiMiddle > ball.y) {
        ai.move(38);
      }
    }
  }

  function draw() {
    if (paused === false) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
      renderPaddle(player);
      renderPaddle(ai);
      renderBall(ball);
    }
  }

  function renderPaddle(paddle) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
  }

  function renderBall(ball) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
    ctx.fill();
  }
  var heldDown = {};
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(keyInfo) {
    heldDown[event.keyCode] = true;
  }, false);
  window.addEventListener("keyup", function(keyInfo) {
    delete heldDown[event.keyCode];
  }, false);

  function playPong() {
    tick()
  }
</script>



<script>
  function getOff() {
    alert("you've been on for five minutes now. Time to take a break.");
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("it's been 10 minutes now. Get back to work.");
      close();
      var body = document.getElementById('hide5')
      body.style.display = 'none'
    }, 300000);
  }
  setInterval(getOff, 300000)

  }
</script>
<script>
  function hide() {
    var games = document.getElementById('games')
    if (games.style.display === 'block')
      games.style.display = 'none';
    else {
      games.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }

  function show() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('my')
    canvas.style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>


<button onclick='hide()'> Hide or show the games</button>
<button onclick='PausePlay()'> Pause games </button>
<button onclick='playPong()'> Play pong </button>
```